# Red light on motherboard "CPU"

Tags: cpu, motherboard

This is the first computer I've built, so I am brand new to this.

MotherBoard: [Gigbate x570 Master](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/X570-AORUS-MASTER-rev-10#kf)

CPU: [Amd 7 Series 3700x](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SXMZLPK)

Ram: [2x 8gb 3200MHz Corsair RGB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D1XCKWW)

So I have a red light on the motherboard labeled "CPU". Looking this up, I've tried these solutions:

1. Switching around RAM
2. Taking out the CPU and putting it back on.
3. Taking out as many components as I can that aren't essential (Only CPU/MOTHERBOARD/PSU)
4. Clearing the CMOS
5. Unplugging and re-plugging the power supply wires.

So everything is working (fans are spinning, lights are on), but it won't boot up. Every single component is brand new, the CPU *looks* fine, but it's very hard to tell with all of the pins.

What else should I try to fix this? What more information do I need to add in order to get help? (Trying to avoid having to replace the parts, but if it comes to that)

Edit 1:

- No motherboard beeps
- `00` displayed on the motherboard's screen

Comment: You'll need to provide a bunch more information if you want this to be less of a guessing game. Can you please provide details on your CPU and RAM? On the motherboard there is a 2 digit debug display, does that show anything?

Comment: Added info to original post.

Comment: That `00` is probably `D0`, which indicates a CPU Initialization Error. You might have to test this board with a known working CPU.

Comment: on a 7 segment display `d0`  looks quite different to `00`

Comment: If you remove all the RAM, you *should* get stuck on a different code.  Can you test if that's true?

Comment: you're going to need a video card of some sort to run that motherboard.